# Regular Expression in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I am trying to match a string in SAS and it seems that after several trial it's not doing what it was supposed to do.

The string is

> ABCD5.170.022.MN

The regular expression is

```
/[a-zA-z]{4}d{1}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\[a-zA-Z]{2}/
```

Can somebody correct me in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is not a period, `.` matches any character.   Escape it and your regex should work fine.

Comment: Like this /([a-zA-z]{4}d{1})[.](\d{3})[.](\d{3})[.]([a-zA-Z]{2})/

Comment: I am using "bracket" to keep its meaning

Comment: Usually you use \ to escape, like, \. means 'period'.

Comment: Did that but it was of no use. So emraced the brackets.

Comment: @Cyborgx37, thanks for the plug, I don't worry too much about that sort of thing in these cases ;)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Sorry for coming late.Its Done now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it ......

```
\w{4}\d{1}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\w{2}
```

For future users, "dot" may or may not be used inside bracket as Joe suggested.

Comment: `\w{4}\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\w\w` is 7 characters shorter :)